# Fetch user details from multiple tenants in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, multi-tenant

I have 3 tenants - t1,  t2, t3.

I have a single page application (Angular) which searches the user and display the details of the selected user.

This application is deployed in t1, using app services, and is able to fetch the users of t1 using graph api.

What I need is,

1. I should be able to fetch users from all the 3 tenants.
2. Users of these 3 tenants should be able to access the application.

I am using

- [MSAL for angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular) for authentication
- Graph API to fetch users and user details
- App services to deploy the application

Comment: I've got some thoughts on these N-tenant applications in my blog: https://joonasw.net/view/best-practices-for-n-tenant-azure-ad-applications. It might help you here.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your application [muti-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)(Any Azure AD directory), the users from any tenants will be able to access the application and fetch users.

If you want to limit the tenants(only t1,t2,t3) to access your application, you can refer to @juunas's blog which mentioned in the comment. This is a good article regarding Limiting tenant access.

Comment: Well, that is possible, but what about fetching the users from multiple tenants?

Comment: @ForamkumarParekh Tenant A user can fetch users in tenant A, users in tenant A can not fetch users in tenant B.

Comment: I understand that, but what if i need to achieve that? is there any solution/work around.
Can I expose any api from t2 tenant and access it in t1 tenant?

Comment: @ForamkumarParekh If your api from t2 tenant is a muti-tenant application. You will be able to access it in t1 tenant if user/admin from tenant1 consent to it.

Comment: @ForamkumarParekh Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: the first requirement is that I should be able to access the users of all the 3 tenants. When I say this, I do not mean authentication, but say for eg. using graph api, fetch users of all the 3 tenants.

Hope this helps explain my constraint.